# Copying non blank cells from sheet to another while linking another cell ref

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a specific range (A2:B50) from sheet1 to sheet 2 while ignoring blank cells. And add a Key between both sheets which is located in B1 after each column pasted for x rows. For example:

[image]

to become this in Sheet2:

[image]

And upon each copy, if I wanted to add new data, it will add on top of the existing data in Sheet2.

This is my code and it does not work as intended, any assistance?

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:B11")

.AutoFilter 1, "<>"

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & cel.Row).Value = cel.Value

Next

.AutoFilter

End With
```

Comment: Any assistance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim lRw As Long, rw As Long, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim cDest As Range, v, v2, k
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'or activeworkbook
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    'next empty row on destination sheet (in "key" column, but offsetting to A))
    Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2)
    k = wsSrc.Range("B1").Value 'key value
    
    lRw = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of source data
    For rw = 3 To lRw
        v = wsSrc.Cells(rw, 1).Value
        v2 = wsSrc.Cells(rw, 2).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Or Len(v2) > 0 Then  'if either cell has a value 
            cDest.Value = v                'write values
            cDest.Offset(0, 1).Value = v2
            cDest.Offset(0, 2).Value = k   'write key
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Edited  - for any specified number of source columns:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 3 'or whatever
    
    Dim lRw As Long, rw As Long, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim cDest As Range, k
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'or activeworkbook
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    'next empty row on destination sheet (in "key" column, but offsetting to A))
    Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, NUM_COLS + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -NUM_COLS)
    
    k = wsSrc.Range("B1").Value 'key value
    
    lRw = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row       'last row of source data
    For rw = 3 To lRw                                      'loop over source rows
        With wsSrc.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS)
            If Application.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then         'if any cell has a value
                cDest.Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value = .Value   'write values
                cDest.Offset(0, NUM_COLS).Value = k        'write key
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0)             'next destination row
            End If
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to get it working but I can not make it copy more than two columns, I changed these and it still did not work.
    Dim cDest As Range, v, v2, v3, k and v3 = wsScr.Cells(rw, 3).Value and wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 4)

How can I increase the copy range from just two columns to more than two?

Comment: Any assistance please?

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time. it worked but there's one issue.
This part: If Application.CountA(.Cells) > 0
I use a macro to clear the cells and replace it with "", it does not count as True Blank. and if you do a test over the empty cell, it returns with FALSE. despite having no value.  

The old code "If Len(v) > 0 Or Len(v2) > 0 Then" works flawlessly. I tried changing it to this: 
 "If Application.CountBlank(.Cells) = 0 Then"
and it still does not ignore the empty non true blank cells.

Comment: nvm. Fixed it by changing my second macro .Value="" to .Clear 

Thank you so much